# How to override get_queryset() whilst using UpdateView Django

Tags: django, django-views

I have inherited UpdateView and I am trying to override the get_queryset() method, but it keeps throwing an error:

*raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Generic detail view UserProfileManagement must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.
*

I am trying not to use slugs etc. in my urls.py.

**models.py**

```
    class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
        start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

        objects = CustomUserManager()

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.first_name = self.first_name.capitalize()
            self.last_name = self.last_name.capitalize()

            return super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.email
```

**managers.py**

```
    class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

        def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password, **extra_fields):
      
            if not email:
                raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
                email = self.normalize_email(email)
                user = self.model(email=email,
                                  first_name=first_name,
                                  last_name=last_name,
                                  **extra_fields)
                user.set_password(password)
                user.save()
                return user

(create_superuser deliberately omitted)
```

**urls.py**

```
(I do not want to use slugs etc.)
    app_name = 'users'

    urlpatterns = [
        path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
        path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
        path('account/', views.UserProfileManagement.as_view(), name='profile'),
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
    class UserProfileManagement(UpdateView):
        model = User
        template_name = 'users/user_profile.html'
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
        

        def get_queryset(self):
            queryset = super(UserProfileManagement, self).get_queryset()
            return queryset.filter(pk=3)
```

However, if I override the get_object() instead it works.

```
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return User.objects.get(pk=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `Model` instead of `model`:

```py
class UserProfileManagement(UpdateView):
   model = User  # Here
   template_name = 'users/user_profile.html'
   fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']

   def get_queryset(self):
      queryset = super(UserProfileManagement, self).get_queryset()
      return queryset.filter(pk=3)
```

Comment: So I did - thank you RedWheelbarrow. I have updated my question, but now I am getting another error:  raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Generic detail view UserProfileManagement must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

Comment: @CanDo add your urls.py in your question

Comment: I am trying not use use any slug etc. in the url. Given that I have supplied the pk to the get_queryset() surely that should be enough, shouldn't it??

Comment: Ok, I've updated to include urls.py

Comment: No is not enough because `get_object` needs that value. Try to override also the `get_object` method (as you originally did). I advice you to use another view, because UpdateView is meant to be called with a pk/slug/.. in the path